# Calculate manually IP Header checksum

Tags: c#, .net, checksum

I want to calculate manually `IP Header checksum` in `c#` and found [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/ip-header-checksum/).
Now i want to implement in but the only thing i didn't understand in this exapmle is the lase step: 
After get the last result of `4E19` it says:

> So now 0100111000011001 is our final result of summing up all the 16
>   bit words in the header. As a last step we just need to do a one’s
>   compliment of it to obtain the checksum.

```
4E19 -> 0100111000011001
B1E6 -> 1011000111100110 // CHECKSUM
```

So the only thing i want to know is how to reach `B1E6` from `4E19`

Comment: how to do what via code ?

Answer (score 2):

That [one's-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) is just inverting all bits, you can do this by XOR-ing with `0xFFFF`:

```
ushort a = 0x4E19;
ushort b = (ushort)(a ^ 0xFFFF); // b = 0xB1E6
```

Or use `~` to invert all bits:

```
ushort a = 0x4E19;
ushort b = (ushort)~a; // b = 0xB1E6
```

Comment: I have my ip header in byte[], what is the best option to add pairs for example 45 and 00 should be 4500, do i need to concatenate it ?